# Unable to run Golang application on Docker

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to run this project - https://github.com/JumboInteractiveLimited/codetest

I've downloaded the Docker tool box, and I've executed the build and run commands as mentioned on the GitHub page, but when I try to access http:localhost:8080, the page is still unavailable.

When I try to execute run again, Docker says

```
"$ ./run.sh
Listening on http://localhost:8080
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon:    driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint quirky_mcnulty (32af4359629669ee515cbc07d8bbe14cca3237979f37262882fb0288f5d6b6b8): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated."
```

***Edit***: To clarify, I get that error only when I run the 2nd time. When I ran the run command first, it didn't complain. I ran it another time just to confirm that it's running.

When I initially ran, I got the following:

```
$ ./run.sh
Listening on http://localhost:8080
2017/10/24 13:51:53 Waiting...
```

Comment: Something's already listening on port 8080. Use a different port, or disable whatever is already listening there.

Comment: Try stopping that other container first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change run.sh to replace port 8080 to 8082

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Listening on http://localhost:8082"
docker run -p 8082:80 codetest
```

I have changes port to 8082 if the port is already in use change that port again to some other port based on your available port.

If you are on Windows

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8082 listenaddress=localhost connectport=8082 connectaddress=192.168.99.100(IP of the Docker)
```

Here is the helping discussion on port farwarding in windows with docker [Solution for Windows hosts](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15740#issuecomment-200409378)

Comment: thank you very much. I had to run this netsh to get it working. Now it works even with 8080 after I ran this command. what does it do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems quite clear

```
port is already allocated
```

which means that some other program is listening on port 8080.
If you are on a Linux system you can try to run

```
sudo lsof -i :8080
```

to find out what is.

Otherwise, simply use another port.

Comment: To clarify, I get that error only when I run the 2nd time. When I ran the run command first, it didn't complain. I ran it another time just to confirm that it's running.

Comment: This is answer never help for the question asked above.